# Efficient/easy way to do simple set manipulation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Have two large set of words (strings).

Would like to subtract one set from the other. The resulting set would contain only the words not found in the second set.

What is an efficient way to do this? Must I do this by hand in excel, write a program. I haven't run across any existing tools or programs that do this.

**Details**
Just as an FYI. The reason I want to do this is that I have two sets of city names. One set includes all the cities within a 50 mile radius of a point. The second set contains all of the cities within a 200 mile radius of a point. I am trying to get the set that contains all of the city names in the doughnut-shaped   section between the 50 mile radius and 200 mile radius.

Comment: Depends on how your data is given. Do you have your city names in a data structure within another program, or just in a, say, textfile, or as a database? Do you need a programm that can do this for any list of city names, or just one time for a particular list of names? How do you calculate the distance from a city to this particular point? Or has someone else calculated for you and gave you just the results?

Comment: Are you stuck with Excel, or is that just a devil you know? It's a simple program in Python, assuming your two datasets are in some reasonable format e.g. text files with one city per line.

Comment: They are in text format. They can easily be copied and pasted into excel. Using a programming language is of course a viable solution, I wouldn't consider it easy though. At least not insofar as I can ask my marketing people to do it and they could get it done without me having to get involved.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the data in Excel, you can select all the data in both lists.  On the "Home" tab, click on Conditional Formatting and choose Duplicate Values.  Change "duplicate" in the dropdown menu to "unique" and say OK.  Then you have the set difference highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

In most programming languages, it's an easy task. Put the city names in two separate files, one city by line; the program will read both files, put their contents in lists, subtract one list from another, and return the result.

If you must use Excel, and work manually, put the cities in two separate columns, and sort each column by itself. Then:

1. Pick the bottom value from the second column, find it in the first column, and delete both values.
2. Repeat item 1 above until there are no more values in the second column, or the remaining values in the second column aren't in the first column.
3. Re-sort the first column, remove blank cells, and you're done.

The sorting allows you to find quickly the position of the item, by [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).